# navigateByUrl in canActivate

Tags: angular

I see some example code here:

https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/keep-data-in-the-state-object-during-navigation-in-angular-5657af156fb8

The specific code is:

```
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, { url }: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean 
  {
       if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
             this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth', { state: { redirect: url } });
       }

       return this.authService.isLoggedIn;
  }
```

What exactly will happen here if this.authService.isLoggedIn = false?

navigateByUrl is then called in this function, **before** this.authService.isLoggedIn is returned, how will this behave? Will the function return "false" as value "immediately"? Or will CanActivate be "aborted" somehow by the navigateByUrl function?

A bit tricky to explain, but it seems strange to return a value from a CanActivate function that is not relevant anymore... because you have navigated away from the page that was requested...

Comment: If you have a slow connection, I don't think you would be navigating to the `/auth` path; returning `false` means to stop the navigation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return `false`, but in addition it will redirect the `user`.

This is useful when you try to navigate to some routes where only the logged in user should be able to navigate. So, if the user is not logged in you will probably redirect him to `Login Page` and return `false`. When you return `false`, then current navigation will be cancelled.

> Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if a route can be activated. If all guards return true, navigation continues. If any guard returns false, navigation is cancelled.

You can also return a [UrlTree](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlTree), and in that case the current navigation will be canceled and a new navigation will start.

> If any guard returns a UrlTree, the current navigation is cancelled and a new navigation begins to the UrlTree returned from the guard.

Comment: Yes, I see that it works, but it seems strange that you can cancel navigation, but in the same function do another navigation. It seems that there would be some kind of race condition...

Comment: The current navigation will wait for the `canActivate()` response in order to be fullfiled or canceled.

Comment: Does that mean that if the canActivate function returns true, any navigateByUrl statements in the function will be “ignored” and the original navigation would be carried out?

Comment: I think that in that case, it would be a race condition. That is why you navigateByUrl if you want to return false.